# Optimizing repeated modulus within a loop

Tags: c, optimization, bitwise-operators

I have this statement in my c program and I want to optimize. By optimization I particularly  want to refer to bitwise operators (but any other suggestion is also fine).

```
uint64_t h_one = hash[0];
uint64_t h_two = hash[1];
for ( int i=0; i<k; ++i )
{
    (uint64_t *) k_hash[i] = ( h_one + i * h_two ) % size;   //suggest some optimization for this line.
}
```

Any suggestion will be of great help.

Edit: 
As of now `size` can be any `int` but it is not a problem and we can round it up to the next prime (but may be not a power of two as for larger values the power of 2 increases rapidly and it will lead to much wastage of memory)

`h_two` is a 64 bit int(basically a chuck of 64 bytes).

Comment: Do you know anything about `size`?

Comment: I have edited the question to make a few things clear as you demanded

Comment: There are methods out there that make repeated divisions/modulus over the same number very efficient. But it's not trivial.

Comment: can you suggest some links for me to read up a bit.

Comment: Here it is: http://gmplib.org/~tege/divcnst-pldi94.pdf But like I said, non-trivial.

Comment: I am doing a project in which I have to optimize something so may be this will be a useful resource then but for now I think you were right. Thanks anyways.

Comment: I've updated your title to better highlight the problem. It's not as general as before, but the modulus is undoubtedly going to be the interesting part. Feel free to roll back if you don't like it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

so essentially you're doing

```
k_0 = h_1 mod s
k_1 = h_1 + h_2 mod s = k_0 + h_2 mod s
k_2 = h_1 + h_2 + h_2 mod s = k_1 + h_2 mod s
..
k_n = k_(n-1) + h_2 mod s
```

Depending on overflow issues (which shouldn't differ from the original if size is less than half of `2**64`), this could be faster (less easy to parallelize though):

```
uint64_t h_one = hash[0];
uint64_t h_two = hash[1];
k_hash[0] = h_one % size;
for ( int i=1; i<k; ++i )
{
    (uint64_t *) k_hash[i] = ( k_hash[i-1] + h_two ) % size;
}
```

Note there is a possibility that your compiler already came to this form, depending on which optimization flags you use.

Of course this only eliminated one multiplication. If you want to eliminate or reduce the modulo, I guess that based on `h_two%size` and `h_1%size` you can predetermine the steps where you have to explicitly call `%size`, something like this:

```
uint64_t h_one = hash[0]%size;
uint64_t h_two = hash[1]%size;
k_hash[0] = h_one;
step = (size-(h_one))/(h_two)-1;
for ( int i=1; i<k; ++i )
{
    (uint64_t *) k_hash[i] = ( k_hash[i-1] + h_two );
    if(i==step)
    {
        k_hash[i] %= size;
    }
}
```

Note I'm not sure of the formula (didn't test it), it's more a general idea. This would greatly depend on how good your branch prediction is (and how big a performance-hit a misprediction is). ALso it's only likely to help if step is big.

edit: or more simple (and probably with the same performance) -thanks to Mystical:

```
uint64_t h_one = hash[0]%size;
uint64_t h_two = hash[1]%size;
k_hash[0] = h_one;
for ( int i=1; i<k; ++i )
{
    (uint64_t *) k_hash[i] = ( k_hash[i-1] + h_two );
    if(k_hash[i] > size)
    {
        k_hash[i] -= size;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 It's actually possible to completely remove the modulus in your first approach if you can prove that `k_hash[i-1] + h_two` will never overflow the integer. But seeing as how it's a hash, I'm going to assume that the numbers are pretty much random.

Comment: @Mysticial `size` was an int though, and the rest are uint_64's, so they shouldn't overflow (h_two can of course be pre-reduced)

Comment: @harold, the it looks like we have a solution. Precompute `h_two % size` and start with `h_one % size`. Then at each iteration, add it to an accumulator. Then use an if-statement to test if it's greater than `size` and subtract if necessary.

Comment: @Mysticial: actually my second solution is more or less that, except that I predetermine the step where the modulo should happen. A simple > would probably be more readable and just as efficient though, I'll add it.

Answer (score 0):

If size is a power of two, then applying a bitwise AND to size - 1 optimizes "% size":

```
(uint64_t *)k_hash[i] = (h_one + i * h_two) & (size - 1)
```

Comment: making `size` a power of 2 is too much to ask for but we can have it as a prime so can you suggest something in that case